# Prospect Management & Tracking

Tags: extension

Are there any extensions which allow for Prospect Management & Tracking? I came across a planned extension called "INTEGRATION WITH DONORSEARCH" but it doesn't look like it has been completed yet, though target date was February 15, 2017.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out [CiviProspect](https://github.com/compucorp/uk.co.compucorp.civicrm.prospect).  From the README:

CiviProspect provides the core structure for creating/ managing/ converting the fundraising opportunities of an organisation. It can also be used to manage any monetary opportunities such as sales opportunities and event sponsorships.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it Donor Search just helps you find better matches, but for managing and tracking that's what CiviCRM already does. You would just use contacts and activities, and if you want something slightly more structured there is CiviCampaign.

If what you're really asking about is tools to help you find prospects in the first place, then that's a slightly different question.

Comment: Having used commercial donor management software like Raiser's Edge or Ellucian Advance, I am used to prospect management and tracking being a separate module, with the ability to capture prospect stage, prospect status, inclination, capacity, annual giving likelihood, planned giving likelihood, major gift likelihood, target gift range etc. I guess if there is no extension which captures this information in CiviCRM, I'l have to create a set of custom fields.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on the DonorSearch extension.  I spoke to my sponsor last week, who said it was done except for documentation.  I would go ahead and install it - I believe DonorSearch allows a free account for CiviCRM users that gives 50 searches per month.

It looks like the [1.1 branch](https://github.com/greenleafadvancement/com.greenleafadvancement.donorsearch/tree/v1.1) is the most current.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Where would I find the extension?

Comment: @RajaMukherjee I just edited my question to reflect that.